# Displaying error messages to the Excel user from an RTD Server

Tags: excel, rtd

Is there a way to display details of an error to the user other than putting #ERROR# in the cell? I would like to validate the topic arguments and somehow prompt the user with the correct format if they are incorrect.

If this isn't possible, is there another way to provide help on the argument format from within Excel?